# Set Interpretation of number of ways 6 different objects put into 10 different cells

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

**Question from book**: In how many ways can 6 different objects be put into 10 different cells such that in a cell there won't be more than one object.
**Answers:**
**Method 1:** In every cell there will either be one object or there won't be any object. We'll choose the 6 cells into which we will put the objects. This can be made in $ { 10 \choose 6 } $ ways. Since the objects are different, then the ordering between them matters. Thus the number of possibilities to put the 6 objects in 10 cells is:  $ { 10 \choose 6 } \cdot 6! = \frac{10!}{4!} $
**Method 2:** Order all the objects one after the other into the different cells: for cell #1 - 10 possibilities , for cell #2 - 9 possibilities and so forth. So by multiplication principle, the number of possibilities is $ P(10,6) = \frac{10!}{4!} $
**My difficulty:**
I solved the problem using method 1 but when I tried to write the sets participating in the multiplication and the resulting set then things looked weird, here's what I did:
$ { 10 \choose 6 } $ represents the set $ \alpha =  \{ \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \} ,\{1,2,3,4,5,7 \},\{1,2,3,4,5,8 \},... \} $ where the numbers from 1 to 10 are the indices of the 10 different cells.
$ 6! $ represents the set $ \beta =  \{ (ABCDEF) , (ABCDFE) , (ABCFDE) ,... \} $ where the symbols A,B,C,D,E,F represent the 6 different objects.
By multiplication rule $ \gamma =  \alpha \times \beta = \{ ( \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \} , (ABCDEF) ) , ( \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \} , (ABCDFE) ) ,... \} $ ~ $ { 10 \choose 6 } \cdot 6! $

However, looking at the elements of the set $ \gamma $, they are ordered pairs and I can't make sense out of them, they don't look like they're representing to me lists of 6 objects ( lists because the objects are different so order matters ) with the fact that they're put in different cells. However I was thinking maybe the elements represent to me some sort of bijections from the first element in the ordered pair to the second? ( for example: maybe the first ordered pair in $\gamma $ represents a bijection from $ \{1,2,3,4,5,6 \} $ to $ (ABCDEF) $ ? ).

**My questions:**
So essentially, I'm asking; what does the set $ \gamma $ above represent to me?, am I right that the elements of $ \gamma $ represent bijections from 1st element ( which is a set ) in the ordered pair to 2st element? What the set of the "number of ways" of 6 different objects put into 10 different cells should look like?

Comment: Element $(\{2,4,5,6,7,9\},EFABDC)\in\gamma$ corresponds with the event that object $E$ is placed in box $2$, object $F$ is placed in box $4$,...,object $C$ is placed in box $9$. So the elements of $\gamma$ represent the possibilities. Consequently its cardinality is the answer to the initial question: "how many possibilities are there?"

Comment: I thought about this but wasn't sure. So the element represents some sort of bijection from $\{2,4,5,6,7,9\}  $ to $ EFABDC $?

Comment: You could say that. The question in the title can be reworded as: "how many **injections** are there from $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$?" Then the example in my comment is the injection that sends $E$ to $2$, et cetera and the set $\{2,4,5,6,7,9\}$ is actually the image of that injection. If we then regard it as a function not to $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ but to image $\{2,4,5,6,7,9\}$ then we can speak of a bijection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The element $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\},(ABCDEF)\}$ is just the encoding of the fact that object $A$ goes to box 1, $B$ to $2$ etc.

You're just counting the number of injections (1-1 maps) from the set of objects to the set of boxes, in essence. So the number of $6$-combinations out of $10$, or indeed $\binom{10}{6}\times 6!$. Or,  the first object has $10$ options, the second $9$ etc so we get $$10\times 9 \times 8\times 7 \times 6 \times 5$$ options directly, but in a calculator that only has a binomial function, it's handy to write it as that product for computation purposes. We don't need to see that specific product as the result of some product rule, though I showed that we could, if we wanted to.

Comment: For the example of the element $( \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},ABCDEF )$ ; I think the general definition of the injection for this example is better to think of as $f: \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} \longrightarrow  \{A,B,C,D,E,F \} $ .
Then since $ABCDEF$ is a list in the example, it can be written as the set $ \{ (1,f(1) ) ,(2,f(2)),(3,f(3)),... \} $
where $ f(1) = A  , f(2) = B,... ,.f(6) = F $.
So we can think of the element $( \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},ABCDEF )$ as $( \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},\{ (1,f(1) ) ,(2,f(2)),(3,f(3)),... \} )$. Is this also a correct interpretation of the example?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 The injection is from $\{A,B,C,D,E,F\}$ to $\{1,2,3,\ldots,10\}$, not as you do. In the (set, list) the resulting injection is to map the list in the list order to the boxes which are always considered in increasing number order.

Comment: So we denote the injection ( to $ \{1,2,3,4,5,6\}  $ ) as $f: \{A,B,C,D,E,F \} \longrightarrow \{1,2,3,4,5,6\} $ Then since $ABCDEF$ is a list in the example, it can be written as the set $ \{ (A,f(A) ) ,(B,f(B)),(C,f(C)),... \} $. Where $ f(A) = 1  , f(B) = 2,... ,.f(F) = 6 $.  
So we can think of the element $( \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},ABCDEF )$ as $( \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},\{ (A,f(A) ) ,(B,f(B)),(C,f(C)),...  \} )$ . Is it okay to write the list ABCDEF in the way I have done under the injection I wrote?

Comment: @hazelnut_116 No, if we have a set $S$ of size $6$ in $\{1,2,3\ldots, 10\}$ write it in a unique way as $\{S_1,\ldots,S_6\}$ so that $S_1 < S_2 < \ldots S_6$ and if we also have permutation  $L$ of $ABCDEF$, then the resulting $f$ from $(S,L)$ (the injection) is $\{(L(1),S_1),(L(2), S_2), \ldots (L(6), S_6)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The $abc$ component can be used to transform the $123$ component into a unique result.

This is the complete table for placing $3$ distinct objects into $4$ distinct cells, object $k$ is placed into cell $c_k$.

$214$ for example meaning:

> Place object $1$ into cell $2$, object $2$ into cell $1$ and object $3$ into cell $4$.

|  | abc | acb | bac | bca | cab | cba |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **123** | 123 | 132 | 213 | 231 | 312 | 321 |
| **124** | 124 | 142 | 214 | 241 | 412 | 421 |
| **134** | 134 | 143 | 314 | 341 | 413 | 431 |
| **234** | 234 | 243 | 324 | 342 | 423 | 432 |

Comment: This is nice; when you said "The abc component can be used to transform the 123 component into a unique result" then this is exactly the kind of relationship I immediately saw when a-priori trying to write the outcome in set-theoretical fashion as I wrote $ \gamma $.